# Is an algorithm to find all primes up to $n$ that runs in $O(n)$ time fast?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

I kindly ask you if it is useful or fast for a prime number generator to run in $O(n/3)$ time?

I believe I have a way to generate all $P$ primes up to $n$, quickly and neatly, in $P$ comparisons and $n/3$ calculations.

Comment: you need to be more specific, I think. But note that $O(n/3)=O(n)$, so you might be confused about what the notation means.

Comment: n / 3 step and at each step a comparison to generate prime numbers up to n @ThomasAndrews

Comment: "generate prime numbers up to n"  generate P primes up to a number n @martycohen

Comment: You will have greater success if you spend some time on clear explanations of your process, especially if you give an *algorithm* rather than random equations.  Your numerous publicity notes about your O(1) factoring algorithm have been unreadable.

Comment: @DanaJ 14.04 and 8.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the primes up to $n$ in $O(n)$ time isn't particularly fast, and nor is it particularly slow. A naive Sieve of Eratosthenes works in time $O(n \log n \log \log n)$ and is very easy to implement. It can be sped up to run faster than $O(n)$ using some wheel techniques. I believe one can reduce the time to $O(n/\log n)$. See *Paul Pritchard, A sublinear additive sieve for finding prime numbers, Communications of the ACM 24 (1981)* for more, or look up Pritchard's Wheel.

Another common algorithm is the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin), which naively runs in $O(n)$, but which can also be sped up to sublinear time.

So no, it's not particularly interesting or special to come up with another algorithm to find the primes up to $n$ in time $O(n)$.

*As an aside, you might read what allowed others to speed up the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the Sieve of Atkin to see if it would allow you to speed up your algorithm.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The difference is that this is a generator of primes not a sieve.
Can find the next prime in {[next primes] - [primescurrent]} / 3

Comment: Both the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the Sieve of Atkin generate primes. I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: First I have to be sure of that http://www.albericolepore.org/fattorizzazione-di-lepore/

Comment: I think the $n/\log{n}$ result is for the number of additions, and the bit complexity is still $O(n)$.